# cant call function defaultCube or stopCube

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

What is keeping me from being able to call any of these functions except the first one? I tried using  also Button onclick in the body. I am using ajax jQuery. Is there something missing in the code or am I missing something badly. Thanks for any help!

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#defaultCube').imagecube(); 
        });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

$(function () { 
    $('#stopCube').toggle(function () {
        $(this).text('Start');
        $('#defaultCube').imagecube('stop');
    }, function () {
        $(this).text('Stop');
        $('#defaultCube').imagecube('start');
    });
});


$('#removeCube').toggle(function(){
        $(this).text('Re-attach');
$('#defaultCube').imagecube('destroy');
},
    function(){
$(this).text('Remove');
$('#defaultCube').imagecube();
});
}

</script>
```

Comment: Please mention the body of page which is being used by you.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna call above function by button onlick then you can use either

$('#buttonID').click(){
  put function body here
});

or

wrap the function in a another function like

function cube(){
 put function body here
}

and call "cube" on button' "onclick" event.

The first one solution you need not call the function , it will automatically call on button click.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried both of those things and it didn't work. That's why I thought something must be wrong within the code. I am a newbe to jquery so I must be leaving something out some place.